# How do I add multiple targets to a .pbxproj file using cordova-node-xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, widgetkit, eas

I am writing an expo plugin to add a widget and a widget configuration target to my app. I'm leveraging the cordova-node-xcode library to modify the .pbxproj file to add my two widget related targets to my app.

Both of my widget targets share some files with each other and the main app target as well. I am running into an issue where basically it says "no parent found filename.swift, SourcesBuildPhase, SourcesBuildPhase".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is specifically for an EXPO Managed workflow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PiotrTomasik Yes, specifically for the EAS managed workflow

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you must build it ejected and then try to use this library to match the ejected build

Comment: Yes I have already built everything in an ejected (prebuild) state. This issue stated is coming up when I use this library to match the ejected (prebuild) state